# Android thread/process not stopping after a set time

Tags: android, multithreading, function, timer

I am trying to get the audiorecord function to stop after so many seconds.  The recording works but it is not stopping after a given duration.

I have tried placing these items in my onClick, as well as in the try portion of the function being called but each time I get the same result, app keeps running.

Looking around stackoverflow and other sites I have tried different ideas on threads, handler postDelayed and timers but nothing seams to work.

I have removed the audiorecord stuff from my code below to just focus on the duration setting.  The code is at the last item I tried.

I appreciate any assistance.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    recordStarted=true;
    recordAudio();
    final Runnable stopRecording = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            recordStarted=false;
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(stopRecording, 3000);

    //Start the delay of stopping the recordin

}

public void recordAudio () {
    try {

        while(recordStarted) {
            counter++;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    String counterS = String.valueOf(counter);
    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "counter = " + counterS, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems is for variable access optimization in Java VM.
You have to declare recordStarted variable as volatile:

```
    private volatile boolean recordStarted = false;
```

Or better to use synchronized context:

```
    private Object sync = new Object();
    .....
    synchronized (sync) {
       recordStarted=false;
    }
    .....
    synchronized (sync) {
       while(recordStarted)
          ...
    }
```